# free-jqgrid grid content loaded while display:none the vertical scrollbar always occludes last column

Tags: jqgrid

tldr; want the <4.7 width and vertical scrollbar handling (including the whitespace when the number of rows < than would require vertical scrollbar)

Migrating to 4.13 from 4.5 and the grid width is always wrong because of the resizing introduced in 4.8 and later.  My grids have a fixed height, scrollrows:true, and a variable number of rows.

My application requires that all my 10+ grids have their data loaded while the parent DIV is display:none distinct (jqui .tabs)  Users don't want the "data" flashing when they switch tabs, so the grid must be completely rendered before display:none is removed.  visibility:hidden won't work because it disrupts the other parts of the page/application.

This worked fine in 4.5.4 but not now.

With 4.13, the vertical scroll bar always occludes part of the last column and forces a display of an unwanted horizontal scrollbar.

How can I get 4.13 to use pre 4.7 width correctly so the vertical scrollbar is correctly placed and without a horizontal scrollbar when rendered inside a display:none parent DIV.

In the code below you'll need to use your own paths to the jqui/jquery/jggrid css and js as I serve them from my own server.

Code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Scroll Grid Loaded While Container is display None</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jquery/jqui/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/free-jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jqui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/free-jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    .displayNone {display:none;}

    </style>

<script>



function csGridDN (elID,caption) {

this.ID                     = elID;
this.selIRow                = 0;
this.selICol                = 0;
this.maxIRow                = 0;
this.Caption                = caption;
this.InitialRows  = [ {"Idx":1,"Col1":"1A","Col2":"1B","Col3":"1C"}];
this.BlankRow     = {"Idx":0,"Col1":"1A","Col2":"1B","Col3":"1C"};


};

$(document).ready(function() {initPhase1();});

csGridDN.prototype.init = function() {

   $(this.ID).jqGrid({
      datatype: "local", 
      height: 22*11,
      shrinkToFit:false,
      caption: this.Caption, 
      autoresizeOnLoad: false,
      adjustGridWidth:false,
      cmTemplate: {resizeable:false,sortable:false,autoResizable:false},
      colNames:["Idx","Col 1", "Col2", "Col3"], 
      colModel:[
         {name:'Idx',       index:'Idx', width:20, sorttype:"int",hidden:true},
         {name:'Col1',      index:'Col1', width:40, colTitle: "Col1"},
         {name:'Col2',      index:'Col2', width:30, colTitle: "Col2"},
         {name:'Col3',      index:'Col3', width:50, colTitle: "Col3"}
         ],
       multiselect: true,
       multiboxonly: true,
       hidegrid: false,
       scrollrows: true,
       cellEdit: false,
       cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
       footerrow: true,
   }); 


};


csGridDN.prototype.clearData = function () {
   var aRows = [].concat(this.InitialRows);
   for (var l = 0; l<aRows.length;l++) {
       aRows[l].id = aRows[l].Idx;
   }

   $(this.ID).jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
   this.maxIRow = aRows.length; 
   $(this.ID).setGridParam({ 'data': aRows, 'rowNum':this.maxIRow });
   $(this.ID).trigger("reloadGrid");

}


csGridDN.prototype.setData = function (aRows) {
   for (var l = 0; l<aRows.length;l++) {
       aRows[l].id = aRows[l].Idx;
   }

   this.maxIRow = aRows.length; 
   $(this.ID).setGridParam({ 'data': aRows, 'rowNum':this.maxIRow });
   $(this.ID).trigger("reloadGrid");

}

function reloadGrid () {
   theGrid.setData(dataRows);
   $("#notice").html("Grid was reloaded while #container was NOT \"display:none\". Scrollbar placement is now correct. jqGrid 4.5.4 puts the scroolbars correctly regardless of the display of the #container.  free-jqgrid only places scrollbars correctly when grid is loaded while NOT \"display:none\"");
}

function initPhase1() {

theGrid = new csGridDN("#DNGrid","Display None");
theGrid.init();


dataRows = [
    {"Idx":1, "Col1": "01A","Col2":"01BB","Col3":"01CCC"},
    {"Idx":2, "Col1": "02A","Col2":"02BB","Col3":"02CCC"},
    {"Idx":3, "Col1": "03A","Col2":"03BB","Col3":"03CCC"},
    {"Idx":4, "Col1": "04A","Col2":"04BB","Col3":"04CCC"},
    {"Idx":5, "Col1": "05A","Col2":"05BB","Col3":"05CCC"},
    {"Idx":6, "Col1": "06A","Col2":"06BB","Col3":"06CCC"},
    {"Idx":7, "Col1": "07A","Col2":"07BB","Col3":"07CCC"},
    {"Idx":8, "Col1": "08A","Col2":"08BB","Col3":"08CCC"},
    {"Idx":9, "Col1": "09A","Col2":"09BB","Col3":"09CCC"},
    {"Idx":10, "Col1": "10A","Col2":"10BB","Col3":"10CCC"},
    {"Idx":11, "Col1": "11A","Col2":"11BB","Col3":"11CCC"},
    {"Idx":12, "Col1": "12A","Col2":"12BB","Col3":"12CCC"},
    {"Idx":13, "Col1": "13A","Col2":"13BB","Col3":"13CCC"},
    {"Idx":14, "Col1": "14A","Col2":"14BB","Col3":"14CCC"},
    {"Idx":15, "Col1": "15A","Col2":"15BB","Col3":"15CCC"},
    {"Idx":16, "Col1": "16A","Col2":"16BB","Col3":"16CCC"},
    {"Idx":17, "Col1": "17A","Col2":"17BB","Col3":"17CCC"},
    {"Idx":18, "Col1": "18A","Col2":"18BB","Col3":"18CCC"}
    ];

theGrid.setData(dataRows);



$("#container").removeClass("displayNone");


}

</script>

</head>

<body>

 <div id="theTop">

  <p>Content Above Grid</p>

  <p id="notice">Grid was loaded while #container was "display:none".  Scrollbar placement is wrong.</p>

 </div>

 <div id="container" class="displayNone">

  <table id="DNGrid"></table>



  <p>Other Content Below Grid: Part of the div #container default of display:none</p>

  <p><button onclick="reloadGrid()">Reload Grid</button></p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have a large number of jqui .tabs and several grids on many of those.  As currently implemented, there is no logic directly relating which grids are on which tabs, so it is a lot of work to make that correlation just call the fix... routine when they (the tabs) become display:block, especially when all versions of jqgrid prior to free-jqgrid simply worked.
[image: Loaded with display:none]

[image: Reloaded without display:none]

Comment: You should provide the JavaScript code which you use or provide the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem. Which version of free jqGrid you use? 4.13.3? Without the demo I can only guess what you do. You can try to call `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` method **after you make the hidden grid visible**: `$("#gridId")[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding();`

Comment: Updated with code example, and why I think having to track the relationship between my jqui .tab and my grids is suboptimal.  Thanks for looking at it though. If free-jqgrid could have an option to calculate the width like <4.8 -- that would be great.  I can see why you changed it, but it makes free-jqgrid unusable for me.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer on my questions. Which version of free jqGrid you use? (4.13.0, 4.13.3, ...??) Do you tried to call `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` after you make hidden div visible?

Comment: Using 4.13.4pre from GIT (Date: 2016-05-20 from the .src.js file) The code is example only.  **In my actual webapp, there are a large number of tabs many with several grids, and I never built in a relationship between the tabs (and its events like becoming the active tab and the loss of the display:none) and any grids**, because all the versions of jqGrid I used always created grids correctly despite being in display:none divs when loaded/updated.